# Appointment invite wont send VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, send, appointment

I don't work in VBA very often and I modified the code below to fit my needs and it works up to the point of actually sending out the appointment invite. When I open it in Outlook the attendee is listed but I have to send it manually from Outlook. I don't get any errors or any indication that it didn't send. Any other tips on optimization and conventions are also appreciated, I'm sure it's painful to look at for some of the better programmers. Also, I know it's similar to other questions on the site but they are different enough I'm having a hard time figuring out what I need to do exactly, so your patience is appreciated.

Thanks :)

```
Sub RegisterAppointmentList()
'Adds a list of appointments to the Calendar in Outlook
Dim olApp As New Outlook.Application
Dim olAppItem As Outlook.AppointmentItem
Dim r As Long

On Error Resume Next
Worksheets("Schedule").Activate 'Insures that the correct sheet is selected, needs to be updated if rename
Set olApp = GetObject("", "Outlook.Application")
On Error GoTo 0

If olApp Is Nothing Then 'If GetObject fails then creates a new Application Object

    On Error Resume Next
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0

    If olApp Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Outlook is not available!"
        Exit Sub
    End If

End If

r = 2 'First row with appointment data in the active worksheet, ignores headers

'Declares variables for Outlook Parameters

Dim myStart, myEnd, myUnitBefore
Dim myAttendee As Outlook.Recipient

While Len(Cells(r, 1).Text) <> 0 And Len(Cells(r, 4).Text) <> 0

    'Sets Default Values of 8:00am and 8:30am as start and end times if no value found
    If Cells(r, 5) = "" Then
        myStart = DateValue(Cells(r, 4).Value) + "8:00:00 AM"
    Else:
        myStart = DateValue(Cells(r, 4).Value) + Cells(r, 5).Value    'Concatenates Date and Start Time to single value
    End If

    If Cells(r, 6) = "" Then
        myEnd = DateValue(Cells(r, 4).Value) + "8:30:00 AM"
    Else
        myEnd = DateValue(Cells(r, 4).Value) + Cells(r, 6).Value 'Concatenates Date and End Time to single value
    End If

    'Set "Minutes Before" if "Days" "Hours" or "Weeks" are selected.
    If Cells(r, 9) = "Hours" Then
        myUnitBefore = 60
    ElseIf Cells(r, 9) = "Days" Then
        myUnitBefore = 24 * 60
    ElseIf Cells(r, 9) = "Weeks" Then
        myUnitBefore = 24 * 60 * 7
    Else
        myUnitBefore = 1
    End If

    Set olAppItem = olApp.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem) 'Creates a new appointment

    With olAppItem

        On Error Resume Next
        .Subject = Cells(r, 1)
        .Location = Cells(r, 2)
        .Body = .Subject & " - " & Cells(r, 3).Value
        .Start = myStart
        .End = myEnd
        .ReminderSet = Cells(r, 7)
        .ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = Cells(r, 8).Value * myUnitBefore
        .Categories = Cells(r, 10).Text & " Category"   'Allows using dropdown to set Category.
        Set myAttendee = olAppItem.Recipients.Add(Cells(r, 11))

        If Cells(r, 12) = "Free" Then
            .BusyStatus = olFree
        Else
            .BusyStatus = olBusy
        End If

        On Error GoTo 0

        .Save 'Saves the new appointment to the default folder
        .Send 'Doesn't seem to work...

    End With

    r = r + 1 'Cycle until all rows of events have been created

Wend

'Clear Objects when done
Set olAppItem = Nothing
Set olApp = Nothing
```

Comment: You may find.Send is disabled. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48104512/how-to-send-mail-when-the-send-does-not-work For future questions try to remove unnecessary code. Fewer possible responders will ignore the question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please comment out or delete all lines starting with 'On Error' - if there are any problems these are just hiding them. Report back what you find and we should be able to help.

Comment: It's possible that .Send is disabled, I can't change the settings so that approach may not be an option.  I removed all the On Error lines and I don't get any errors.

Answer (score 3):

B. Blaze

I’m not sure if you want to create an Appointment or a Meeting?

However, the difference between Meetings and Appointments is that the meeting has attendees, and the appointment is not.

So if you would create a Meeting, you should setting “olAppItem.MeetingStatus = olMeeting” property.

For more information, please review the following link:

[AppointmentItem.MeetingStatus Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.appointmentitem.meetingstatus)