# Email displays but does not send

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am testing out sending emails from Excel using VBA.

I do not get an email sent to my inbox.

The code is below:

```vb
Sub email_from_excel()

Dim emailApplication As Object
Dim emailItem As Object

Set emailApplication = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set emailItem = emailApplication.CreateItem(0)

'Now build the email
emailItem.to = "emailaddress@test.com"
emailItem.Subject = "This is a test y'all."
emailItem.Body = "This is a test message ya'll."

'Send the email
emailItem.Send

End Sub
```

In line 6 of the code, I put my email address in between the quotation marks.

I enabled Microsoft Outlook under Tools - References in VBA.  No error comes up, but no email gets sent.

I commented out the `emailItem.Send` and added in `emailItem.Display` ran the code and an email showed.

Comment: Add `emailItem.Display` and comment out the send line.  Does an email show?  Is there a email profile on the machine in question?  Your code is fine and does work.  may also want to look at Outlook>>Options>>Trust Center>>Trust Center settings??Macro Security

Comment: @Sorceri I commented out the emailItem.Send and added in emailItem.Display ran the code and an email showed.  There are two email profiles set up.  Could that be what is causing it not to send? The Trust Center settings are set to Notifications for digitally signed macros.

Comment: your code works fine. i have 3 email profiles within outlook and it works

Comment: Your code should work. Check your `Sent` box. Is the email there? If yes, then login to your email not from outlook but in a browser and then check your `Spam` folder. Have the emails landed there?

Comment: I check my sent folder and spam folder in both emails and there is no email there.

Comment: Is it possible that it is not working because I have a gmail address set up in Outlook?

Comment: @VictoriaV  ok, with my previous suggestion, now hit send.  Does it show up if you manually hit the send button?  Open task manager; Do you have multiple instances of Outlook running?  This is sounding like a security issue and not a coding one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send mail when the .Send does not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48104512/how-to-send-mail-when-the-send-does-not-work)

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that message submission is an asynchronous process. You need to wait for the message to go out before releasing (and thus closing) Outlook.

As a test, start Outlook before your code runs - this way it will stay open even after your code is finished executing.

Comment: Hi, Yes I keep Outlook open while the code runs and it still does not work.

Comment: Are the messages present in the Outbox folder? Do they go out if you hit "Send and Receive"? Have you tried to call emailApplication.Session.SendAndReceive?

Answer (score 0):

I've been through the same problem, what seems to be happening is the Excel deletes outlook from memory before sending the message,

Before the solution here comes a tip, instead of using create object you can declare the variable as application.outlook and application.mailitem
It makes all the methods and propertys appears as hint while you type

Well, I solved it by declaring a global variable to store outlook.application
Global appOutlook as application.outlook

Then in "this workbook" inside the open event I set the variable
Set appOutlook = new application.outlook

Now within the macro that send the e-mail you declare an set the variable to store de email

Dim eMail as Outlook.mailitem
Set eMail = appOutlook.CreateItem(olMailitem)

Also you can improve your code by using with statement
With eMail
.to
.body
End with
Instead of type the car name every time u can use with and then you just need to type a dot and access the methods and propertys

Now the last part is to set eMail to nothing
Set eMail = nothing
I don't know why this is necessary, but my codes usually don't send the e-mail without it
Well this should make it works, you can use a local variable, but if you need to send more than one email in a short time, then any one you go, they will be in some kind of "void" and you go when you run a code that actually works, by using a global variable to store the application, it starts and only stops if you code it, the application crashes or closes, well sorry for the big text, and i hope to help