# Attaching Specific files to corresponding recipients

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, mailing-list

I have a long list of cost reports to be sent to different recipients.

I was thinking I could have one Excel file with addresses and corresponding Location i.e 
A1 John.smith@com.com A2 0001 
B1 Jeff.smith@com.com B1 0002

Then using VBA cycle through each row (1) and search a folder for the corresponding (A2) named file and attach it to mail out to cell (A1).

Comment: You are on the right track. Column A has emails. Column B has file location. Loop through column A to get email and Column B to attach. This link is a great start. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17883088/excel-vba-sending-mail-using-outlook-send-method-fails. (Not sure why user had issue with `.Send` but it always work for me.) So, set up a loop in your workbook and apply the `To` from Column A and `Attachment` from Column B and fill the rest out as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have headers in the first row. **Untested.**

```
Sub AntMan()

Dim OutLookApp As Object
Dim OutLookMailItem As Object
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim MailDest As String
Dim subj As String

lastRow = ThisWorkbook.WorkSheets("Sheet6").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'change worksheet

For i = 2 To lastRow

    Set OutLookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
    Set OutLookMailItem = OutLookApp.CreateItem(0)
    Set Attach = OutLookMailItem.Attachments

    With OutLookMailItem
        .To = Cells(i, 1).Value
        .SUBJECT = "Put your subject here"
        .Body = "Put your body here"
        Attach.Add "C:\your\file\path\here\" & Cells(i, 2).Value & ".xlsx"
        .Display 'for debugging
        .Send
    End With

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: What it you don't have outlook?  Can other email clients be used like "Windows live 2012" or "Thunderbird".

Comment: @HarveyFrench OP didn't specify.