# Unable to send Bulk emails through excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, email-attachments

I have written a code to send bulk email to all recipients through a list from excel.
however, it does not attach the attachment and also it does not send the document.
in case we bypass the attachment, it only creates the email but does not send the email.

```
Sub Sendemail()

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim myAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
Dim lastrow As Long

lastrow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastrow
Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

With olMail
.To = Cells(i, 1).Value
.Subject = Cells(i, 2).Value
.Body = Cells(i, 3).Text
.Attachments.Add Cells(i, 4)
.Display
.Send
End With

Set olMail = Nothing
Set olApp = Nothing

Next i

End Sub
```

[image: Excel file image]

the above code should send the emails directly to the recipients.

Comment: The send question may be a company policy security issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17883088/sending-mail-using-outlook-where-the-send-method-fails.

Comment: Comment out the `.Display` and keep only `.Send`. As for the attachment, what type and size is it?

Comment: .Attachments.Add Cells(i, 4).Value

Answer (score 0):

The [Attachments.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachments.add) method creates a new attachment in the `Attachments` collection. The source of the attachment can be a file (represented by the full file system path with a file name) or an Outlook item that constitutes the attachment.

You need to copy the file from the shared/network folder to any local folder and then use a local file path for attaching a file. The `Attachments.Add` is not designed to deal with file shares or any other URLs.